# Multiple citations with page reference each within same parenthesis in a memoir-based class

Tags: citing, memoir, multiple-citations, abntex2

I'm using a class called abntex2 which is based on memoir. I need to accomplish the follwing:

Dummy text dummy text dummy text (Author1, year, p. X; Author 2, year, p.Y; Author3, year, p. Z; ... ; AuthorN, year, p. P).

My question is: how?

Comment: The `memoir` class as such is pretty agnostic to citing, as far as I recall. Look into `natbib` or `biblatex`, depending on what you use. Your class might load the citation package for you, you might want to inspect its documentation and/or source text.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you use a software tool -- say, BibTeX -- to create the formatted bibliography. If that's the case, I suggest you employ the `natbib` citation management package and, specifically, its `\citealp` macro, to create the desired look of the citation call-outs.

[image]

If you use the `biblatex` package (and `biber`, presumably, as well), I suggest you load it with the option `natbib=true`; this will let you use the `\citealp` macro.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.bib}
@misc{1,author="Author1",year=3001,title="Thoughts"}
@misc{2,author="Author2",year=3002,title="Thoughts"}
@misc{3,author="Author3",year=3003,title="Thoughts"}
@misc{N,author="AuthorN",year=3010,title="Thoughts"}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bib stle

\hypersetup{hidelinks} % optional

\begin{document}
(\citealp[p.~X]{1}; \citealp[p.~Y]{2}; \citealp[p.~Z]{3}; \dots; \citealp[p.~P]{N})
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```